# Find objects with quotes

Tags: sql, oracle

ORACLE objects can be named like so "Last Name". The question is: how to find these objects? Tables, columns, etc.

Table user_tab_columns not found a flag that indicates that this column is such an object is not specified.

Do not kick me hard, I do not know much English.

[image]

I need to find the columns, similar to those shown in the figure, a list of all.

Comment: Interesting question, but your last example is incorrect.  You can create a column with a # without using quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

Quote:

> ORACLE objects can be named like so "Last Name". The question is: how to find these objects?

Oracle always stores object names in uppercase by default. So, in order to find quoted object names (it should be noted that those double quotation marks wont be present in the data dictionary), we simply need to identify objects with at least one lower case alphabetic character in their names.

It should be noted that this approach does not take into consideration the fact that a quoted table name might be an oracle reserved word in uppercase(`TABLE` for instance. You cannot create table named `TABLE` unless you enclose `TABLE` in double quotation marks)

```
/* There were no quoted identifiers created */

SQL> select t.table_name
  2    from user_tables t
  3   where regexp_like(t.table_name, '[[:lower:]]');

no rows selected

/* create table with quoted name */

SQL> create table "Table_Name"(
  2    col number
  3 );

Table created.

/* search for quoted table names */

SQL> column table_name format a30

SQL> select t.table_name
  2    from user_tables t
  3   where regexp_like(t.table_name, '[[:lower:]]');

TABLE_NAME          
------------------------------  
Table_Name
```

If there were illegal punctuation characters included in the table name, you can expand search pattern by adding those punctuation characters you a think table name might contain. For example, `[[:lower:]\.*:]` .

```
SQL> select t.table_name
  2    from user_tables t
  3   where regexp_like(t.table_name, '[[:lower:]\.*:]');

TABLE_NAME        
-------------------
.TABLE  
.table  
TABLE_NAMe
Table_Name
na:me\ 
name*
name\ 
table  

8 rows selected.
```

**Note**: Oracle does not distinguish between regular(not quoted) identifier and quoted identifier in uppercase. That is, `table_name` and `"TABLE_NAME"` are the same, and the latter wont be considered as a quoted identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_instr` to search for symbols other than digits, characters and underline.

Tables, procedures, types etc.:

```
SELECT
    owner,
    object_name,
    object_type
FROM
    all_objects
WHERE
    regexp_instr(object_name, '[^_0-9a-zA-z]') > 0
    AND owner IN ('HR')
;
```

Output:

```
OWNER       OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE     
----------- ------------------------------ ----------------
HR                                         TYPE            
HR          !@#$%^&*(                      PROCEDURE       
HR          BIN$6YKZr90lXr7gQAB/AQAVOA==$0 TABLE PARTITION 
HR          DR$NAME_INDEX$I                TABLE           
HR          DR$NAME_INDEX$K                TABLE           
HR          DR$NAME_INDEX$N                TABLE           
HR          DR$NAME_INDEX$R                TABLE           
HR          DR$NAME_INDEX$X                INDEX           
HR          SYS_LOB0000114402C00001$$      LOB             
HR          SYS_LOB0000114402C00002$$      LOB             
HR          SYS_LOB0000114428C00006$$      LOB             
HR          SYS_LOB0000114433C00002$$      LOB             
HR          SYS_LOB0000115263C00022$$      LOB             
HR          SYS_LOB0000115263C00023$$      LOB             
HR          SYS_LOB0000115717C00002$$      LOB             
HR          SYS_LOB0000115729C00001$$      LOB             
HR          table with spaces              TABLE
```

As you can see, some other objects got into the result set as well.

Columns:

```
SELECT
    owner,
    table_name,
    column_name
FROM
    all_tab_cols
WHERE
    regexp_instr(column_name, '[^_0-9a-zA-z]') > 0
    AND owner IN ('HR')
;
```

Output:

```
OWNER        TABLE_NAME             COLUMN_NAME       
------------ ---------------------- ------------------
HR           CN_PLOT_OVERLAP        SYS_NC00023$      
HR           CN_PLOT_OVERLAP        SYS_NC00022$      
HR           CN_PLOT_OVERLAP        SYS_NC00021$      
HR           CN_PLOT_OVERLAP        SYS_NC00020$      
HR           CN_PLOT_OVERLAP        SYS_NC00019$      
HR           CN_PLOT_OVERLAP        SYS_NC00018$      
HR           CN_PLOT_OVERLAP        SYS_NC00017$      
HR           table with spaces      @monkey_column
```

I have searched for objects only in the `HR` schema - you can change it as you need. Also, if you want to look for specific characters, change the regular expression - instead of:

```
regexp_instr(column_name, '[^_0-9a-zA-z]') > 0
```

to find, for example, `!@#` and `space`, use:

```
regexp_instr(column_name, '[ !@#]') > 0
```

(notice lack of the `^` sign in the beginning - it means "everything else than ...")

Answer (score 0):

List of tables with names that have double quotes:

See the answer Nicholas Krasnov.

The list of columns with names that have double quotes:

```
select * from user_tab_columns a 
where REGEXP_LIKE(a.column_name, '[^A-Za-z0-9_]|(PRIOR)|(COMMENT)|(NUMBER)|(DATE)|(VARCHAR)|(CHAR)|(SYS)')
```

Answer (score -1):

i dont understand much but as far as i understand

you can use system tables like;

```
select * from all_tables
select * from all_columns
```

or

```
select * from user_tables
select * from user_columns
```

Answer (score -1):

View "all_columns" does not exist as far as I know (at least not till Oracle 11.1), try

```
SELECT owner, table_name, column_name FROM all_tab_cols WHERE column_name = 'Last Name';
```